# ImageMagick thumbnailImage Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, imagemagick, max

I use ImageMagick's function `thumbnailImage` to genenerate images. However, sometimes I get the message:

> "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"

One thing I noticed is that the whole thing bombs before 30 seconds is up. But the error given is still that the maximum execution time has been exceeded.

The problem is much more like the link below.
http://xenforo.com/community/threads/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-exceeded-when-uploading-avatars.17982/

Can anybody give some suggestion?

Comment: The entire front page of Google's results for "Maximum execution time exceeded PHP" is dedicated to articles explaining exactly how to fix this.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide your ImageMagick command and version.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem with a maximum execution time of 180 seconds (which is flat out unacceptable).  After much digging, I found the source of the problem and the solution, and I wanted to share it on here for future users who have this problem.

The problem with ImageMagick timing out is due to a bug related to its OpenMP extension.  Essentially, the OpenMP extension is supposed to allow for parallel processing to speed things up.  If you have multiple processors or multiple processing cores on your server, though, the parallel processes can actually block each other from executing and leave the whole thing hanging.

I found that the best solution was to disable OpenMp and recompile the ImageMagick package.

Here is an page that describes what I just said but better (it includes a link to instructions for checking your number of processors and processing cores):
http://www.daniloaz.com/en/617/systems/high-cpu-load-when-converting-images-with-imagemagick/

Here are instructions for how to disable and recompile the package:
http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2011/10/php-image-slow-smp-magick-on-ubuntu.html
NOTE: the first line of code has a typo. It should read:

```
apt-get build-dep imagemagick
```

Comment: hey... do you know if that openmp stuff can be detected with php?

Comment: At the terminal prompt, type `identify -version` and look for "Features".

Comment: Hmm, I have OpenMP on one of my boxes I've been using with the Imagick extension to thumbnail images. In particular I've had multiple Imagicks running simultaneously via screen sessions. Haven't noticed any problems with blocking.

Answer (score 3):

There can be problems with ImageMagick hanging when OpenMP is enabled, so you could try rebuilding it with OpenMP disabled - as indicated by Greg.

To see if Open MP is enabled, tt the terminal prompt, type

```
identify -version
```

and look for OpenMP under "Features"

As a quick test and possible work-around, you could try disabling multi-threading in ImageMgick which should prevent OpenMP doing anything.

To do that, set the ImageMagick environment variable `MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT` to 1 before calling any IM functions.

```
putenv('MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1');
```

Reference material: [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is if you have OpenMP enabled in your ImageMagick then ImageMagick uses multiple CPU cores and if you are using PHP-FPM then it is based on threading, but the max_execution_time you set in your php.ini configuration it is for a single CPU.

In your terminal, execute: `convert -list resource` and see the `Thread` value. It would be higher than 1.

You can either reduce threads to 1 by going into ImageMagick policy.xml:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="1"/>
```

Verify the threads limit again by: `convert -list resource`. It should be 1.

Now restart your PHP-FPM. For example: `service php7.1-fpm restart` and now you will see PHP uses exact max_execution_time as you have set.

---

If you are unable to use terminal you can also set thread limit directly through PHP.
You can also set Thread limit directly through PHP:

```
Imagick::setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_THREAD, 1);
echo Imagick::getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_THREAD);
```

> This constant is available if Imagick has been compiled against
>   ImageMagick version 6.7.8 or higher.

---

But as we are now using single thread the performance of ImageMagick would not be as good as before. So you might increase the thread value in policy.xml and set the max_execution_time to be: `30 * number_of_threads`.

Other solutions would be, difficult but achieves same result as we did above.

1. Rebuild ImageMagick with OpenMP disabled.
2. Use mod_php instead of PHP-FPM.

Comment: I had the same problem on my mac installing Imagick with brew. Limiting the threads in the policy.xml worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function.

If you set it to 0, the script will execute without a limit.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This, of course, will fix your issue but it does not take away that imagemagick shouldn't take that long to make a thumbnail.

I would first check if all the data passed to imagemagick is filled. If something is empty, this could cause an infinite loop. Also, I would try timing how long the script actually takes.

Comment: How is this any different from [Guest](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1085415/guest)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8413936/369450) from 3 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this but i will try to best.

Check the memory limit Increase it least 256MB.

You can limit various resource via time => convert -limit time 1 in.jp2 out.jpg
Check this => 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=9jcfn0pu5vfu215d7r2df55ah1#limit

If you are working large images you can just check the image file size and quit if too large. Also you can do some special large image processing to speed things up so that you are not thrashing.
Check this => http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive

Answer (score -1):

Try `<?php set_time_limit(0); ?>` at top of your PHP file.

Comment: there is nothing to do with this at all. The exec time is just few seconds while it gens this kind of execution time error.